# jQuery: Select Options - Adding Prices

Tags: jquery, select

I'm new to coding.  I have a two part question:

1.Let's say I have:

```
#html    
<style>
    <option value="1"> Red Box </option>
    <option value="2"> Green Box </option>
    <option value="3"> Blue Box </option>
</style>
<style>
    <option value="4"> Red Circle</option>
    <option value="5"> Green Circle</option>
    <option value="6"> Blue Circle</option>
</style>
```

What's the best way to assign each option a Dollar value so that the value can be computed in jQuery?

2.How can jQuery be used to create these results:
 * The selected option prices are totaled and shown to the user
 * The user can choose to "submit options"

Comment: No, I'm not a student.  I work in marketing in the legal field - but making websites has become a hobby of mine.  The box & circle values are just arbitrary to simplify the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The selected option prices are totaled and shown to the user

Simple, just do:

```
  var total = 0;
  $('select').each(function() {
      // Convert val from string to integer, so it isn't cocantenated.
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
  });
 alert('Total is: ' + total);
```

#### The user can choose to "submit options"

Well you would normally want a submit button:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
```

Then you can either let the browser handle the submitting of the form values. To do this each select, or any form element, must be a child of the form. You also define where the form should either post/get values to

```
<form name="shapes" action="/form-handler.php" method="post">
  <!-- your select elements here !-->
</form>
```

Each element in your form MUST have a name attribute if you want it to be submitted correctly.

Should you want jQuery to submit a form via ajax, you can use the beauty `serialize`

```
 $('[name=shapes]').serialize();
```

This will convert the form values to a query string for posting. See http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ for details on this function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gary.  You lost me at ajax =).  I'll try your method also.  I like that you explained your code.  That'll help me and others like me break out of copying & pasting.

Comment: I tried this and it works.  Thank you.  Can you tell me how I would go about adding the "total" into the markup instead of as an alert?

Comment: Instead of the alert, just do: `$('<div>').html('Total is: ' + total).appendTo('body')` -- of course you can change where it is placed, in that example it's placed on the body (at the end).

Answer (score 1):

The best way to assign each option a dollar value is by using the value key of the option tag. It would go something like this:

```
#html    
<select> <!-- I'm assuming you meant a select-tag here not a style-tag -->
    <option value="5"> Red Box </option>
    <option value="8"> Green Box </option>
    <option value="1"> Blue Box </option>
</select>
<select>
    <option value="6"> Red Circle</option>
    <option value="3"> Green Circle</option>
    <option value="1"> Blue Circle</option>
</select>
```

Your jQuery code can look like:

```
var total = $('select:first').attr('value') + $('select:last').attr('value');
```

Comment: So reading this - basically the jquery says that the "total" is the sum of the first value through the last value.  Very cool.  Didn't think it'd be that simple.

Comment: This won't work Tarun it'll show `Nan`, you'll need to do `.val()`

Comment: Please explain further Gary.  I haven't tried any of these yet.

Answer (score 0):

To get the total:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    alert( $('select:first').val() + $('select:last').val() );
  });
</script>
```

Hope this helps. Cheers